# Pure CSS image pan

Tags: jquery, css, animation, slideshow, banner

Can an image be scaled and moved within a wrapper in a  random direction infinite?
How can it be achieved using css keyframes or animation

Link to fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/ke9okv2g/)

I don't know how to do this. I have seen long back a jQuery slideshow plugin which moves the image within a wrapper. I could not find it to

```
<div class="image_wrap">
<img src="/images/img_1.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>

.image_wrap {
   width:580px;
   height:260px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.image_wrap img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transform:scale(1.2);
  animation: 1.2s ease 0s normal none infinite running jump;
}
```

The image should bounce back and forth within a wrapper it should not slide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/s18tnu70/ did you mean something more along these lines? 
(i got this sollution with the help of [Algaros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3571997/alagaros)

```
    .wrapper {
  background-color: #DDD;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/100x100);
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: moveX 3.05s linear 0s infinite alternate, moveY 3.4s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveX {
  from { left: 0; } to { left: 400px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveY {
  from { top: 0; } to { top: 200px; }
}
```

Comment: I think my question is not clear. Is it possible to stick the image within the wrapper. I can see the image white background and it should be move infinite in diagonal as well like bouncing ball game

Comment: @wk I checked early this morning here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/vj91vfd6/. but still I see a white background . I adapted from the page http://carlosmartinezt.com/2014/04/10-more-css-tricks-for-2014-part-2/

Comment: I scaled the image now the background is not showing. But on pause the image does not fits to the screen. http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/vj91vfd6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
.image_wrap img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    transform:scale(1.2);
    -webkit-animation: 1.2s slideImg linear infinite;
    animation: 1.2s slideImg linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideImg {
    from { transform: translateX(100%); }
    to { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes slideImg {
    from { transform: translateX(100%); }
    to { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

Example in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ke9okv2g/2/

Comment: I dont want it to slide. I want it move within a wrapper in slow and bounce back to another side

Comment: anyway thanks you tried and answered to my question . but this is not what I wanted . The image should bounce within the wrapper in an random direction not just jump